# PHP: Regex JSON file for image names

Tags: php, json, regex

I am trying to get all the image names and extensions from a json file.

Currently I have the following pattern:

```
$pattern = '/(.*).jpg/i';
```

When I run the php for this I get the following output:

```
[1506] => "saturday.jpg
[1507] => "friday.jpg
[1508] => "monday.jpg
[1518] => "image": "ten-pound.jpg
[1519] => "image": "hundred-fifty-pounds.jpg
[1520] => "image": "six-pound-fifty.jpg
[1568] => "answer": "thursday.jpg
[1633] => "answer": "london.jpg
```

I do not want anything but the image names. So not the `"image"` or `"answer":` or even the beginning `"`

What I ideally want is all the images to be output into an array like so:

```
$images = {"saturday.jpg","monday.jpg","ten-pound.jpg"}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show us what the original JSON looks like?

Comment: sure, give me a second.

Comment: Try `$pattern = '/[^\s"]+\.jpg/i'`. It won't work if there are spaces in the URLs. It will also match any matching text having 1+ chars other than whitespace and `"` followed with `.jpg`, so the results might not be what you expect.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Wow that worked. Thanks - wanna add it as an answer and I can accept it?

Comment: Please add the example JSON you have, maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your regex approach you need  to only match any 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `"` before `.jpg` (note that `.` must be escaped to match a literal dot):

```
$pattern = '/[^\s"]+\.jpg/i'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DbIhAm/1).

You may achieve what you want by simply walking through the JSON key-value array and grab every value ending with `.jpg` in a case insensitive way using

```
$json = '{"k": {"image": "monday.jpg"}, "k2" : {"image": "ten-pound.jpg"},  "k3": {"image": "hundred-fifty-pounds.jpg"}}';
$j = json_decode($json, true);
$results=[];
function json_recursion($myarray, $needle, &$results = array())
{
    foreach ($myarray as $key => $value)
    {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                json_recursion($value, $needle, $results);
            } else if (substr(strtoupper($value), -strlen($needle)) === strtoupper($needle)) {
                $results[] = $value;
            }
    }
}
json_recursion($j, ".jpg", $results);
print_r($results);
```

Output of the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/bs3Vc):

```
Array
(
    [0] => monday.jpg
    [1] => ten-pound.jpg
    [2] => hundred-fifty-pounds.jpg
)
```